# Как проверить валидность даты на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, валидация

Есть некая дата в формате "год день месяц", например:

```
date = "2008 02 08"
```

Нужно проверить, является ли она валидной. Примеры:

```
"2021 25 12"      ->   Правильная дата 
"2000 01 01"     ->   Правильная дата
"1975 21 01 1"    ->   Неправильная дата (неправильный формат)
"2011 34 06"      ->   Неправильная дата (34 июня не существует)
"2019 29 02"      ->   Неправильная дата (в високосном годе нет 29 февраля)
```

Конечно, можно сделать проверку с кучей `if`-ов, построить сложную регулярку — да, но хотелось бы сделать это как-то попроще.

Существует ли какая-либо функция (из встроенных библиотек или из сторонних), которая проверяет валидность даты?

Comment: Вытащить цифры *не*сложной регуляркой и скормить их в datetime?

Comment: А если бы не выбивающийся пример с запятой, то можно было сразу всё целиком в datetime запихнуть с форматом `%Y %m %d`

Comment: Ах да, ещё определитесь, `год день месяц` или `год месяц день`, в разных примерах у вас по-разному

Comment: @andreymal, я попутал, запятую убрал. А как запихивать в datetime? Я с этим модулем мало знаком.

Comment: @andreymal, и формат даты поправил.

Comment: А без запятой и с конкретным форматом решение становится тривиальным однострочником `datetime.datetime.strptime("2019 29 02", "%Y %d %m")` (ловим исключение ValueError по желанию)

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, а варианты без исключений есть?

Comment: А вам религия запрещает отлавливать исключения?)

Comment: @andreymal, нет, то же тупое желание накорябать жуткий однострочник) С try-except он уже трестрочник. Хотя это не критично.

Comment: С этим наверное будет проблематично, потому что рациональность сомнительная

Comment: @andreymal, ладно, обойдусь так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import datetime
current_day = ''
try:
    current_day = datetime.datetime.strptime("2021 25 12", "%Y %m %d")
except Exception:
    print('Дата не по шаблону')

print(current_day)
```

---

А вот еще прикольная штука

```
from dateutil import parser
def try_date(s):
    try:
        return (parser.parse(s))
    except ValueError:
        return None


d = ["2021 25 12",
     "2000 01 01",
     "1975 21 01 1",
     "2011 34 06",
     "2019 29 02",
     "21/11/01",
     "22-01-02",
     "22-13-12",
     "13.12.2021",
     "12.13.2021"]

for i in d:
    print(i, '->', try_date(i))
```

---

```
2000 01 01 -> 2000-01-01 00:00:00
1975 21 01 1 -> False
2011 34 06 -> False
2019 29 02 -> False
21/11/01 -> 2001-11-21 00:00:00
22-01-02 -> 2002-01-22 00:00:00
22-13-12 -> False
13.12.2021 -> 2021-12-13 00:00:00
12.13.2021 -> 2021-12-13 00:00:00
```

Comment: Зачем заводить isValidDate, если можно просто вернуть False из except?

Comment: Планировал возвращать эту переменную, но прыжки по типам меня остановили, вот еще не знаю если функция не может возвратить нужный результат определенного типа, что ей возвратить?

Comment: None можно вернуть